# Load Google Maps without markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

I have two radio button. When the first is checked, i display a google map with some markers in it . I would like that when i check the second radion button, it display that same map, but without the markers. Could you help please?

```
<div><input type="radio" name="reception" id="rad" value="livraison"> Livraison</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="reception" value="point"> Point de récuperation</div>

<div id="map" style=" display:none; height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){


        var receps=document.querySelectorAll('[name=reception]');

        for (var i = 0; i < receps.length ; i++)
        {
            receps[i].onclick=function(e){

                if(e.target.value == 'livraison'){

                    document.getElementById('map').style.display  = 'block';
                }
                else{
                    //How to display the map without markers
                }

            }
        }
```

There is the callback function of the maps api:

```
function initMap() {

        var sp = {lat: 23.54565, lng: 11.453};
        var metro_a={lat:12.4545  , lng: 13.3148};
        var metro_n={lat:10.934329596  , lng: 10.323665372};
        var lieux=[
                    {
                        nom: "MT" ,
                        coordonnees:{lat: 11.93863, lng: 10.31413}
                    },
                    {
                        nom: "MA",
                        coordonnees:{lat:19.9361  , lng: 10.3148}
                    },
                    {
                        nom:"MN" ,
                        coordonnees:{lat:18.936  , lng: 10.323665372}
                    }
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: sp
        });


        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        for (var i = 0; i < lieux.length; i++) {
            var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position:lieux[i].coordonnees,
                nom:lieux[i].nom,
                map:map
            });

        }
```

PS: i want to switch between the two radio. If livraison is checked , the map is displayed without the markers . If point is checked, the map is displayed with markers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selected radio button has the value "point", display the markers, otherwise don't:

```
var point = document.querySelector('input[name = reception]:checked');
if (point && point.value == 'point') {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < lieux.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: lieux[i].coordonnees,
      nom: lieux[i].nom,
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y19fm8wm/4/)

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="radio" name="reception" value="livraison"> Livraison</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="reception" value="point"> Point de récuperation</div>
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initMap() {

    var sp = {lat: 23.54565,lng: 11.453};
    var metro_a = {lat: 12.4545,lng: 13.3148};
    var metro_n = {lat: 10.934329596,lng: 10.323665372};
    var lieux = [{nom: "MT",
        coordonnees: {lat: 11.93863,lng: 10.31413
        }
      },{
        nom: "MA",
        coordonnees: {lat: 19.9361,lng: 10.3148}
      },{
        nom: "MN",
        coordonnees: {lat: 18.936,lng: 10.323665372
        }
      }];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: sp
    });
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    var point = document.querySelector('input[name = reception]:checked');
    if (point && point.value == 'point') {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < lieux.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: lieux[i].coordonnees,
          nom: lieux[i].nom,
          map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var receps = document.querySelectorAll('[name=reception]');
    //console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[name=reception]'))

    for (var i = 0; i < receps.length; i++) {
      receps[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.value == 'point') {
          console.log('cest un point')
          document.getElementById('map').style.display = "block";
          initMap();
        } else {
          console.log('cest une livraison')
          document.getElementById('map').style.display = "block";
          initMap();
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at which radio button is selected before adding the markers:

```
var selected = document.querySelector('input[name = "reception"]:checked').value;

if(selected === "livraison") {
    for (var i = 0; i < lieux.length; i++) {
        var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
            position:lieux[i].coordonnees,
            nom:lieux[i].nom,
            map:map
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov - That wasn't part of his question, and the implementation of that requirement really depends on factors that aren't mentioned in the question.  Besides that point, there would still need to be a condition that is based on which radio button was selected.